# KeyChain Access and GPG Keychain - should those be running simultaneously?

Tags: gnupg, keychain

I have installed GPG Suite and found out also during this time that my OS X has some KeyChain Access app that stores all my passwords under my screenlock password - total news to me. Can I get rid of Apple app if I now have GPG? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not an OSX user, but can you point the Apple KeyChain to the GPG keychain?

Comment: How?  This is quite expert, we need some good answers.  Thanks :  )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OS X keychain app is a component deep in the core, and not only takes care of several login and account passwords, but also the Safari web password store and handles certificates for a broad number of OS X applications from both Apple and third parties.Removing it would possibly break all of those.

GnuPG only handles OpenPGP keys (it *could* also do S/MIME, but rarely is used for this purpose). GnuPG is not a replacement for any of the tasks the OS X key chain is performing, there is rarely any overlap in-between them (apart from they're managing keys, although different kinds of).

Comment: That's perfect for an answer for what I wanted to know.  THANK YOU.